# Combining two rows of two different columns in 1 row

Tags: sql

How can I combine two rows in 1 like the table below to have the result table also seen below?

```
ID     NAME      GROUP    OWNER
1      Shoes     Bulls    NULL
1      Shoes     NULL     Michael Jordan
2      Hat       NULL     NULL
2      Hat       NULL     Kobe Bryant
3      Boots     NULL     NULL
3      Boots     NULL     NULL
```

Result

```
ID     NAME      GROUP    OWNER
1      Shoes     Bulls    Michael Jordan
2      Hat       NULL     Kobe Bryant
3      Boots     NULL     NULL
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are this tables database tables? If so i think you have something wrong as you cannot have 2 rows with same ID

Comment: Is this initial table the result of a `JOIN`? The schema does seem pretty odd.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(GROUP) AS GROUP, MAX(OWNER) AS OWNER
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. can't believe I didn't think of it. Spent all day trying to use pivot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(NAME) AS NAME,
    MAX(`GROUP`) AS `GROUP`,
    MAX(OWNER) AS OWNER
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example data shown this will work.

```
SELECT ID, NAME, MAX(GROUP) AS GROUP, MAX(OWNER) AS OWNER
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID, NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

First fix the base tables so that missing information is modelled by the absence of a row (rather than null), provide some viewed tables to provide a default narrative for missing data, then show the result:

(Standard SQL-99 syntax, tested on SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
WITH Apparel  -- base table
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'Shoes'), 
                     (2, 'Hat'), 
                     (3, 'Test')
             ) AS T (apparel_ID, apparel_name)
     ), 
     ApparelGroups  -- base table
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'Bulls')
             ) AS T (apparel_ID, apparel_group_name)
     ), 
     ApparelOwners  -- base table
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 'Michael Jordan'), 
                     (2, 'Kobe Bryant')
             ) AS T (apparel_ID, apparel_owner_name)
     ),
     ApparelGroupsNarratives  -- viewed table
     AS
     ( 
      SELECT apparel_ID, apparel_group_name AS apparel_group_narrative
        FROM ApparelGroups
      UNION
      SELECT apparel_ID, '(no group)' AS apparel_group_narrative
        FROM Apparel
       WHERE apparel_ID NOT IN (SELECT apparel_ID FROM ApparelGroups)
     ), 
     ApparelOwnersNarratives  -- viewed table
     AS
     ( 
      SELECT apparel_ID, apparel_owner_name AS apparel_owner_narrative
        FROM ApparelOwners
      UNION
      SELECT apparel_ID, '(no owner)' AS apparel_owner_narrative
        FROM Apparel
       WHERE apparel_ID NOT IN (SELECT apparel_ID FROM ApparelOwners)
     )
SELECT a.apparel_ID, a.apparel_name,
       g.apparel_group_narrative, n.apparel_owner_narrative  
  FROM Apparel a
       INNER JOIN ApparelGroupsNarratives g
          ON a.apparel_ID = g.apparel_ID
       INNER JOIN ApparelOwnersNarratives n
          ON a.apparel_ID = n.apparel_ID;
```